# VB6 printing issue on the server IIS7 - "Printer Error"

Tags: printing, iis-7, vb6

We have an classic asp- vb6 site setup on IIS7. We are in migration of this app from windows 2003 to 2008. From client browser the url is sent to sever and based on the inputs of request it prints the document by calling comp plus application written in vb6 language. The printing fails when the IIS user is logged off from the server, however it works just fine when it is logged in. The printer installed is a network one, from event logs and app tracer logs i was able to see the network not being available when the user is logged off.

It seems the printer registries details are removed when yhe iis user logoff. The functionality works just fine on windows 2003 server.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: No VB6 question here. Sounds like a simple user context issue in your IIS 7.x configuration.  Is this 2008 or 2008 R2?  Take a look at https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities